# What is the optimal platelet-rich plasma (PRP) infiltration schedule to treat a tendinopathy?

Tags: tendinopathy, prp

I wonder what the optimal platelet-rich plasma (PRP) injection schedule is to treat a tendinopathy.

(1) showed that two PRP infiltrations performed in a one-week interval didn't show any improvement over a single PRP infiltration. I wonder whether there are other studies of that kind, e.g. a study that would compare a single PRP vs two PRP infiltrations performed with a longer interval.

I am mostly interested in the epicondyles of the humerus

---

- (1) Kaux, Jean-François, Jean-Louis Croisier, Bénédicte Forthomme, Caroline Le Goff, Frédéric Buhler, Betty Savanier, Sandra Delcour, André Gothot, and Jean-Michel Crielaard. "Using platelet-rich plasma to treat jumper's knees: Exploring the effect of a second closely-timed infiltration." Journal of Science and Medicine in Sport (2015). https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=10859506660075153178&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22

Comment: I haven't found any answer so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.